# Is it possible to put camel properties in a hazelcast cache?

Tags: properties, apache-camel, hazelcast

I would like to know if it is possible to push property in the cache hazelcast.
I work with a distributed environment and would like properties to be shared across all environments. Is it possible?

My current configuration for loading properties is as follows:

```
<bean id="propertiesConfigurer" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesMode" value="2"/>
    <property name="properties" ref="allProperties" />
</bean>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the distributed data structures of Hazelcast (i.e. IMap) and put any data you want as long as you make them serializable.

Comment: I'm not pro on Spring but maybe you can have another bean as an IMap and put this bean into IMap during application initialization?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a distributed map with entries as `<String, Properties>`. Each entry will keep a set of properties. Or, you can create a simple distributed map with entries as `<String, String>` and use this map as a set of properties.